# consulta MYSQL devuelve datos duplicados

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy teniendo problemas con una consulta:

```sql
SELECT distinct 
asistencia.codAsistencia, 
asistencia.fecha, 
asistencia.mensaje, 
users.nombre, 
contratan.tiempoRestanteBono
FROM asistencia, users, bonos, contratan
WHERE asistencia.codAsistencia = 2 
AND asistencia.usuario = users.id
AND contratan.bono = bonos.codBono
GROUP BY asistencia.codAsistencia, 
asistencia.fecha, 
asistencia.mensaje, 
users.nombre, 
contratan.tiempoRestanteBono
```

Siempre me devuelve los datos duplicados, por ende me está dando problemas en mi código php.

Agradezco toda ayuda

Comment: no hay una relación entre `users` a `bono`, o `users` a `contratan`?

Comment: así es. en contratan.usuario

Comment: puedes mostrar la estructura de cada tabla? para darme una idea de que tanto falta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que, mientras haya un campo con un dato diferente en cada línea del resultado de la consulta, ya no se consideran datos duplicados.

Y puedes estar tranquilo pues, con el `DISTINCT`, los estás eliminando todos.

Otra cuestión es que quisieras, por ejemplo, evitar nombres duplicados. En ese caso, no muestres tantos campos, haz un `SELECT DISTINCT` únicamente del nombre y obtendrás nombres únicos.

El `GROUP_BY` ya es otra cuestión, fíjate en que formas grupos pero no aplicas ninguna función de totales a estos grupos. ¿Para qué hacer grupos entonces? El objetivo de hacer un grupo es contar los registros de ese grupo, sumar algún campo de tipo numérico, buscar máximos o mínimos, o cualquier función de agregación que quieras aplicar. Si no vas a necesitar nada de esto, realmente deberías usar es un `DISTINCT` y harás trabajar mucho menos al servidor.